# Google analytics universal not track event

Tags: universal-analytics

I wish to track event with new universal analytics and I don't have any idea why this doesn't work. I put analytics code right after start off body tag. This code look like this:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
        (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-3843452-1', {'name': 'first'});
ga('first.send', 'pageview');
```

By the way all other standard analytics works fine.

I've use this code for button:

```
<button id="ga-event-send" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'button', 'click', 'test event', 1);">Send ga event</button>
```

I've watch network on chrome developers tools and anything was send. I haven't got any idea what i've been doing wrong.

Thanks for all help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

according to official guide this part

`ga('create', 'UA-3843452-1', {'name': 'first'});
 ga('first.send', 'pageview');`

should look like this 

`ga('create', ''UA-3843452-1', 'auto', {'name': 'first'});  // New tracker.
ga('first.send', 'pageview'); // Send page view for new tracker.`

hope this helps you!